# Opening a pipe on mac's Console.app

Tags: macos

I have a terminal command that spews a lot of output.  I'd like to open that output in the mac's Console.app log viewer.

I know I can pipe my output to a file and then open that file in the Console, but that results in a huge file on my filesystem that I'd rather avoid.

Is there a way to pipe the output of a command to the Mac's Console app?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
yourcommand | open -f -a /Applications/Utilities/Console.app
```

I know the `-f` switch for open reads from STDIN but you might need to restructure piping a bit or the switch order... ive never actually used the option, but check the manpage for `open` for more details.

Comment: Very cool, had no idea that you could do that. +1 for you sir.

Comment: It appears that the file must have an EOF before it will open in the app, so it doesn't seem to work for tailing log files.

Comment: @emmby: oooh, sorry didnt realize that. maybe you could use a uri to `/dev/stdin` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save each run to disk and rotate out the old ones?

Here's a simple recipe for log success:

- mkdir ~/Library/Logs/newapp
- runprogram 2>1& > ~/Library/Logs/newapp/newapp.log_$(date +"%Y-%M-%D-%h-%m-%s")

  Then add a cronjob that does this once a day or hour or whatever..

  cd ~/Library/Logs/newapp/; ls -t | sed '1,10d' | xargs -r rm -v -f

  That will list the log files in order of timestamp, it'll keep the most recent 10 - any others it will delete.

Alternatively - and this is going to sound a bit heavy handed, but.. you should try Splunk. If you have lots of log data to plow through, Splunk works great as a development tool on the desktop. Way more useful than just tailing a log.